# How to plot the sum of procedure's results in 3D?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, procedural-programming

Help me please to draw a graph of the results of my procedure in 3D .
The procedure displays a graph of the function Sin[x] and rectangles on it and Ln [y] and rectangles on it .[image][image]

I need to plot a sum of procedsure's results of Sin[x] and Ln[y]  in 3D, then these rectangles should be parallelepipeds.

```
spxsin = {-1, -0.35, 0.3, 0.95, 1.6, 2.375, 3.15, 3.925, 4.7, 5.025, 
   5.35, 5.675, 6};
spxlny = {1, 2.25, 3.5, 4.75, 6};
operation[value_, f_, a_, b_] := Block[{data},
  data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, a, b, 0.1}];
  Graphics[{Thick, Blue, Line[data],
    Green, 
    Table[Point[{value[[i]], f[value[[i]]]}], {i, 1, Length[value]}], 
    Pink, Opacity[.7], 
    Table[Rectangle[{value[[i]], f[value[[i]]]}, {value[[i + 1]], 
       f[value[[i + 1]]]}], {i, 1, Length[value] - 1}]
    }, Axes -> True]]

operation[spxsin, Sin, -1, 6]
operation[spxlny, Log, 1, 6]
```

I've tried to do it :

```
Plot3D[{operation[spxsin, Sin, -1, 6] + operation[spxlny, Log, 1, 6]}, {spxsin, -1, 6}, {spxlny, 1, 6}]
```

or

```
Plot3D[{operation[spxsin, Sin, -1, 6] + operation[spxlny, Log, 1, 6]}, {x, -1, 6}, {y, 1, 6}]
```

but it doesn't work:(

Comment: I'd suggest you first figure out how to make the 3d plot you want  without the boxes.  Your `Plot3D` statements are nonsense: `operation` returns a 2d `Graphics` object. You cant add `Graphics` objects. What would that even mean?.  `Plot3D` cant take a graphics object as an argument. What would that mean?